# How to fetch data in jQuery - Multiple Tag Select in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am using this jQuery plugin: [jQuery - Multiple Tag Select](http://demonstration.easy-development.com/jquery-mt-select/).
Visit the site to see the plugin.

In this plugin, when you enter a name, like, I want to tag "MARCH", I will just type "Mar", a help will appear with some detail and image.

[Click to see](http://demonstration.easy-development.com/jquery-mt-select/).

The dropdown appear comes from an array like this:

```
$response = array(
    array( 
        'id' => '1', 
        'name' => 'Hamza', 
        'email' => 'Minfo@mhk.me', 
        'picture_path' => 'assets/img/avatar2.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2', 
        'name' => 'Jackqueline Andre', 
        'email' => '8461493908', 
        'picture_path' => 'assets/img/avatar2.jpg'
    )
};
```

Now I want to get this array fetch from database like.
My DB-Details:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM author";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Now I don't know how can I fetch data from the server like above give, can anyone help me?

Comment: use $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

Comment: also not working for me :( I tried it.

Comment: check if $row contains result, using var_dump();

Comment: I am new in php dude, didn't get you.

Comment: yes it show me my db data in an array

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one to in $row array then use

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

If you want to get all the records to be fetched from the result then

```
$output = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

this will make it an array with multiple records as arrays

if you want to use a loop to fetch records one by one then while loop is very easy

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assco($result)){
//do your coding here...
}
```

Note: fetch_assoc will make it an associative array, var_dump($row) will give full variable details such as type of variable and data inside it.